# Tornado import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

I have installed tornado and following works fine, I am able to run `hello,world` app

```
python -c "import tornado"
```

but following results in error

```
python -c ""from tornado.netutil import TCPServer"
```

Import error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name TCPServer
```

full code : I am trying to run this https://gist.github.com/phuslu/1231481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the wrong imports from the wrong package, try the following:

```
import sys, os, re
import logging

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.iostream import IOStream
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
```

as your imports. I've tried and tested it.

Comment: I got the link of that gist somewhere from tornado documents, looks like something has been changed in recent version. I am also getting same error for 'b' , from tornado.util import b, bytes_type. By dir(tornado.util), I couldn't figure out what is sub for 'b'.

Comment: found that tornado removed b pakcage also and added dependency for 'six' . Looks good